# Adding to userform in django before saving in database

Tags: python, django, authentication

Im sure this was working and now it's not. Anyone know what could be up? its failing at the new_user = form.save(commit=False)

```
class Signup(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

    def post(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        new_user = form.save(commit=False)

        email=new_user.cleaned_data.get('email')
        new_user.username=email

        if new_user.is_valid():
            new_user.save()
            username = new_user.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = new_user.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/accounts/home/')
```

Answer (score 0):

That line and the following two should be inside the if block; you can't save if the form is not valid.

Comment: but the form isn't valid until I've copied the email field into the username field. I thought that was the point of the (commit=False) it allows you to add to the form before checking it's valid and committing to the database?

Comment: No, that doesn't affect the form at all; form.save returns a model instance. If your form is not valid because it requires the username, you should exclude that field in the form definition.